# How do I rewrite a facet item label using facetAPI bonus?

Tags: 7, search

I am looking at the code example provided by [Facet API Bonus module](https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi_bonus) in the section Rewrite facet items via callback function

```
function HOOK_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
  if ($settings->facet == "YOUR_FACET_NAME") {
    foreach($build as $key => $item) {
      $build[$key]["#markup"] = drupal_strtoupper($item["#markup"]);
    }
  }
}
```

How would I modify that to override the label of a specific facet item?

Answer (score 1):

This snippet forces the output to be uppercase by using `drupal_strtoupper($item["#markup"]);`. And then sets `$build[$key]["#markup"]` to this new uppercased value.

If you need to check for a specific item, you could use:

```
function HOOK_facet_items_alter(&$build, &$settings) {
  if ($settings->facet == "YOUR_FACET_NAME") {
    foreach($build as $key => $item) {
      if ($item["#markup"] == 'my value') { // Check if this is the right item
        $build[$key]["#markup"] = 'my overridden value';
      }
    }
  }
}
```